# Get image from second table using id from first table in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I have the following queries:

```
posts = Feed.objects.all() //contains all post details including author names
post = Feed.objects.values('author') //contains only author names
for p in posts:
   prof=Profile.objects.filter(user__in=post).values('img') //contains images of author present in post dict object
```

Feed table contains details related to posts and has 'author' field as foreign key. Profile table contains user details and img as a field with 'user' field as OneToOneField(User).

Problem: Not able to retrieve profile pics of user who's posts are shown in the html page. I want to retrieve profile pics of user from Profile table based on the results of Feed table which is stored in Dict object called 'posts'

Comment: What shows in the console when you print prof? If it gives you a path, maybe this can help: <img  src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ ti.poster }}"/> you must indicate in the template {{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ the_field_with_the_image }} or wherever your images are.

Comment: @otrebla.. the following prints in the console: [{'img': u'grumblr/images/user/donnie-yen_74313-1152x864_N7k
mg': u'grumblr/images/user/480x800-Wallpaper_AppsApk_-31.jpg'}]

Comment: @otrebla.. The problem is: I am able to loop thru the posts in html page and print all feed details. But, i am unable to display the corresponding profile pic for each post by author because prof has only 2 images while posts has 5. How to do?

Comment: Can you post the code for you `Feed` and `Profile` models?

Comment: @solaris.. I made a mistake in html page so only it was not displaying. I was probably trying prof.img instead of posts.author.profile.img.